# android: TextView text color based on image;

Tags: android, colors, textview, imageview

I've a TextView on top of an ImageView.

[image]

The image is loaded from server. Image may have light/dark areas. So I want to change the text color according to the image. So I tried color palatte api

```
Picasso.get().load(pic).placeholder(R.drawable.holder).into(iv, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        Palette.from(bitmap).generate(palette -> {
            Palette.Swatch vibrantSwatch = palette.getVibrantSwatch();

            if (vibrantSwatch != null) {            
                name.setTextColor(vibrantSwatch.getBodyTextColor());
                job.setTextColor(vibrantSwatch.getBodyTextColor());
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception ex) {

    }
});
```

It works for some images. For others, vibrantSwatch is null or simply doesn't return the correct color. Does anyone have a perfect solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can slight blur the image and show textview in white color

Comment: @NiravJoshi Sorry, that's not an option for me. Our client requires it, not to add any blur.

Comment: Suggestion: Server side computation of what color works and just load that on some API call?

Comment: I don't think that works since these are images uploaded by peoples.

Comment: https://en.proft.me/2017/07/26/placing-text-appropriate-color-over-image-android/

Answer (score 0):

use this library from google, click [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/palette/graphics/Palette) to read more about it

```
implementation 'androidx.palette:palette:1.0.0'
```

Example of usage

```
Palette.from(bitmap).generate(palette -> {
    //There is alot of methods you can use whatever wherever you want
    int rgb = palette.getMutedSwatch().getRgb();
    int vibrant = palette.getVibrantSwatch().getRgb();
    int vibrantDark = palette.getDarkVibrantSwatch().getRgb();
    int vibrantLight = palette.getLightVibrantSwatch().getRgb();
    int muted = palette.getMutedSwatch().getRgb();
    int mutedDark = palette.getDarkMutedSwatch().getRgb();
    int mutedLight = palette.getLightMutedSwatch().getRgb()
});
```

and this method is useful if you want hex color

```
private String rgbToHex(int rgb) {
    return String.format("%06x", 0xFFFFFF & rgb);
}
```